# How to become a mathematcian?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I study Electric engineering and I have always loved Mathematics and now I want to study math and dont know where to start, I want to be like a one who graduated from a math departement with no difference between us so how shoud I study beside my current study, what plan should I follow and what bboks should I read for every topic ?

Comment: Here's one resource with a bunch of free texts/lecture notes: http://hbpms.blogspot.com/

Comment: Not to cool your passion, just to convey an objective point of view: I do not believe there is any standard operation procedure to achieve such a thing. My experiences tell me that if a person sufficiently wants to do something then the person will find his own way. Of course, others' suggestions are valuable, which should not be viewed as a rule to follow but as a "stimulant".

Comment: I am not a mathematician but I suspect the easiest way is simply to enroll in a university. Maybe you can skip or fly through most of the first or second year though (Edit: my point of view is biased by the fact that where I live university is basically free. If you live in the US and face 30k per year to study then it would be different!)

Comment: Many electrical engineers are extremely good mathematically and study problems with a very high maths content. Perhaps you could do an MSc or PhD with such a research engineer and learn a lot that way as well as doing very good mathematics. Problems in control, stochastic processes, network analysis, coding and many more arise where your background in electrical engineering with a taste for maths will have real value.